# Multithreading file compress

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I've just started to work with threads, 
I want to write simple file compressor. It should create two background threads - one for reading and other one for writing. The first one should read file by small chunks and put them into Queue, where int - is chunkId. The second thread should dequeue chunks and write them down in order(using chunkId) into output stream (file, which this thread created in begin).

I did it. But I cant understand why after my program ends and I open my gziped file - I see, that my chunks mixed, and file doesn't have previous order.

```
public static class Reader
{
    private static readonly object Locker = new object();

    private const int ChunkSize = 1024*1024;

    private static readonly int MaxThreads;
    private static readonly Queue<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> ChunksQueue;
    private static int _chunksComplete;

    static Reader()
    {
        MaxThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        ChunksQueue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int,byte[]>>(MaxThreads);
    }

    public static void Read(string filename)
    {
        _chunksComplete = 0;

        var tRead = new Thread(Reading) { IsBackground = true };
        var tWrite = new Thread(Writing) { IsBackground = true };

        tRead.Start(filename);
        tWrite.Start(filename);

        tRead.Join();
        tWrite.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    }

    private static void Writing(object threadContext)
    {
        var filename = (string) threadContext;

        using (var s = File.Create(filename + ".gz"))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var dataPair = DequeueSafe();
                if (dataPair.Value == null)
                    return;

                while (dataPair.Key != _chunksComplete)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("write chunk {0}", dataPair.Key);

                using (var gz = new GZipStream(s, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                {
                    gz.Write(dataPair.Value, 0, dataPair.Value.Length);
                }

                _chunksComplete++;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Reading(object threadContext)
    {
        var filename = (string) threadContext;

        using (var s = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var counter = 0;
            var buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
            while (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != 0)
            {
                while (ChunksQueue.Count == MaxThreads)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("read chunk {0}", counter);

                var dataPair = new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(counter, buffer);

                EnqueueSafe(dataPair);

                counter++;
            }

            EnqueueSafe(new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(0, null));
        }
    }

    private static void EnqueueSafe(KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> dataPair)
    {
        lock (ChunksQueue)
        {
            ChunksQueue.Enqueue(dataPair);
        }
    }

    private static KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> DequeueSafe()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (ChunksQueue)
            {
                if (ChunksQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    return ChunksQueue.Dequeue();
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    } 
}
```

UPD:
I can use only .NET 3.5

Comment: You should switch to a `BlockingCollection` with a `ConcurrentQueue` as the underlying collection. You won't need to Lock and you won't need the `Thread.Sleep(1)` anymore as it will wait for data to arrive if none is available.

Comment: I forgot to say that I can user only .net 3.5!

Comment: Why not simply read one buffer, and while you compress+write that buffer, read the next? Only one thread is needed, you use async I/O, and don't risk filling up the queue with buffers you've read if the compress+write thread takes more time to do its job than the reading thread.

Comment: Its just a practice. This example doesnt have any connections with real life examples. But thank you for your idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [alexm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32037607/80274) does bring up a very important point that `Stream.Read` may fill `buffer` with less bytes than you requested, the main problem you have is **you only have one `byte[]` you keep using over and over again.**

When your reading loop goes to read a 2nd value it overwrites the `byte[]` that is sitting inside the `dataPair` you passed to the queue. You must have a `buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];` ***inside*** the loop to solve this problem. You also must record how many bytes where read in and only write the same number of bytes.

You don't need to keep the `counter` in the pair as a `Queue` will maintain the order, use the `int` in the pair to store the number of bytes recorded as in alexm's example.

Comment: Ok, I see. I've edited my code like @alexm and you explained, now I write all bytes in there order. I've replaced counter, its not necessary now, as you said. But I have last question - why alexm told me to edit Writer and put as third parameters - value key (instead of value length...)?

Comment: I think it is mistake. The third parameter is Length of writing buffer.

Comment: @matterai Because buffer holds garbage data at the end of it, it is not 100% full of the data you want. In alexm's answer he holds in the key the length of the "good bytes" that you want to read, in the writer you need to only write the "good bytes" in and exclude the junk ones at the end.

Answer (score 3):

`Stream.Read()` returns the actual number of bytes it consumed. Use it to limit the size of chunk for the writer. And, since there is concurrent reading and writing involved you'll need more than one buffer. 
Try 4096 as the chunk size.

Reader:

```
var buffer = new byte[ChunkSize]; 
int bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

while (bytesRead != 0)
{  
   ...
   var dataPair = new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(bytesRead, buffer); 
   buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
   bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Writer:

```
 gz.Write(dataPair.Value, 0, dataPair.Key)
```

PS: The performance can be improved with adding a pool of free data buffers instead of allocating new each time and using events (e.g. `ManualResetEvent`) to signal *queue is empty*, *queue is full*  instead of using `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: A nice trick for `Stream.Read` I learned to consolidate the two read calls use `for (int bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); bytesRead != 0;  bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) { ... }` instead of a while loop.

Comment: @alexm so... had my chunks mixed cause I have concurrent reading and writing? Am I right?

Comment: @matterai kinda, they where mixed because you where overwriting the `byte[]` you passed in to your queue, if you did not have concurrent reading and writing you could have gotten away with it, but because you can have two reads before you have 1 write you must make a new `byte[]` every loop. However you do also have a 2nd bug of not respecting the length of bytes that was read in which is what alexm focuses on in his answer.